# python: filter with weighted footprint

Tags: python, python-3.x, filter, weighted-average

I would like to use a "footprint filter with weights" in Python. I tried to use the `generic_filter` from `scipy.ndimages.filters`. But it does not take weights. A little bit more details: I do have meteorological data and I would like to create weighted means in 4 main directions (North, South, East, West). Therefore I create a user-defined footprint matrix as shown in this post.

The problem: the `generic_filter` just takes `bool` footprints and converts my nice filter matrix into `True` when `> 0` and `False` when `== 0`. The effect: I don't get a weighted mean, the function just returns the mean over the lower "pyramid".

I was searching for a few hours in different packages but haven't found anything useful. Probably I am searching at the wrong end of the spectrum? Does anyone have a hint for me? Thanks a lot!

[image: User-defined footprint. Covers southerly area with a gaussian weighting scheme from the center point]

Comment: Did you mean to put a link to "this post"?

Comment: No, sorry, this post is just the one you are reading. Thanks for spell correction jonrsharpe :)